# Storing a variable in session without cookies ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, session-variables, razor-pages

I need to store a boolean in the session object, but I can't use cookies because iframe won't allow the cookie.

So I need to be able to store a variable in the session - any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: the session key is always stored in cookies. Your requirement is just invalid. Could you tell more about the reason behind it? We may have an alternative solution then.

Comment: Hello king i found a solution to my problem :D i added a p3p header to allow my cookie and now its all guuci :D

Comment: Hi @KasperHammer, Glad to hear you have found the solution, congratulation! And, I suggest you could post your solution as an answer, it can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Besides, if you want to store data locally within the user's browser, you could try to use the [web storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), see [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).